# FL studio route one mixer track to another

Tags: mixer, fl-studio

Can I redirect the audio output of a mixer track to another mixer track ?

There is send to Insert XX. But it also sends the sound to Master. I want to route the sound completely to an insert track I choose.

I expected the "Out" select dropdown to have a list of mixer tracks where to route the audio, but it only shows "none"...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FL12, you can right  click on the upward facing arrow on what channel you want to send it to, at the bottom of each mixer strip, and choose "Route to this track only" or "Sidechain to this track only".

https://gyazo.com/c0e86bc9654fbb37742349429560a5d6

Answer (score 0):

You can, turn off the arrow under the main channel. this will stop routing the output to the main track.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove from master**

Select a track like insert 1 in the picture. You will see that a Send Indicator is lit below the master track and insert 1. Click on the Send Indicator on the master track to remove the routing between insert 1 and the master track.

**Route to custom track**

Simply select a track like insert 1 and press the Send Indicator below an other track. Press the Send Indicator below insert 2 for example and insert 1 will be routed to insert 2.

**Picture**

[image: FL Studio mixer]